# Unable to rotate xticklabels of all subplots under seaborn figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have a figure with multiple subplots.
For some reason, the `set_xticklabels` method does not work for these subplots.

Here is the code am using:

```
n_rows=len(customers)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(n_rows,2, figsize=(18,72))
fig.suptitle('Mytitile',fontsize=16)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
#fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.97)
sns.set_style("ticks")
for i,client in enumerate(customers):
    df = df1[df1['Client'] == client]
    sns.lineplot(data = df, x='date', y='income',ax=ax[i,0]).set_title(client)
    ax[i,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
    sns.lineplot(data = df, x='date', y='cost',ax=ax[i,1]).set_title(client)
    ax[i,1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
```

I was hoping

```
ax[i,0].set_xticklabels(ax[i,0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right')
```

would do the trick, but it isnt. (It simply vanishes the labels altogether)
Any ideas why and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler to use [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) to set the rotation,

```
ax[i, 0].tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)
```

`'x'`, `'y'`, or `'both'` can be specified for the (optional) first argument (default is `'both'`) and will control to which axes the label rotation is applied.

Perhaps you should try that instead